# Restrict the Data Table to change culture

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I am using a multi-lingual project. In that when I change the language, numbers in the data table also changes. I want to restricts this change. Here is my code

```
public DataSet ExportFarmers(CustomerAssignmentDataModel searchDataModel)
    {

        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[8];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserId", searchDataModel.UserId);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@LanguageId", searchDataModel.LanguageId);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@BusinessUnitIds", string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDataModel.BusinessUnitIds) ? "0" : searchDataModel.BusinessUnitIds);
        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@ZoneIds", string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDataModel.ZoneIds) ? "0" : searchDataModel.ZoneIds);
        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@RegionIds", string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDataModel.RegionIds) ? "0" : searchDataModel.RegionIds);
        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@TerritoryIds", string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDataModel.TerritoryIds) ? "0" : searchDataModel.TerritoryIds);
        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@VillageIds", searchDataModel.VillageIds == "null" ? "0" : searchDataModel.VillageIds);
        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@CustomerTypeId", searchDataModel.CustomerTypeId);

        DataSet ds = DbHelper.ExecuteSQLSPToGetDataSet("SpExportFarmers", param);

        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Farmer";
        ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Farmer Crop";

        ds.AcceptChanges();
        return ds;
    }
```

In this data table one column is there and it change the format according to culture. But I want to restrict.

Comment: It is unclear what is asked here. What is the input, expected output and current output?

Comment: the current output is there is one column having decimal value 45,000000 but in Stored Procedure it is 45.000000.So the expected output is 45.00000

Comment: If that is an number datatype then you're only looking at differences in the culture setting when your data is represented. This is not something that should or could be solved in the dataset or datatable. It is an presentation issue that needs to be handled by the UI.

Comment: Numbers doesn't have a format until you actually go and convert them to strings, so the problem here is not with the *storage* of the numbers (unless you're storing them as text), it is with your displaying of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your application default `CultureInfo`. To change this you should use this line in your application startup.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

or, If you want to use `en-US` culture info:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Something like:

```
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

More about `CultureInfo` you can look from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)